# Registry access denied

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, regedit

I edited `["HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"]` and set the administrator permissions to "Deny".

Now, when I try to open any file it gives me this message:

"Your Internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened".

Any solutions?

Comment: yeah, in windows its never safe to take admin access from much of anything, except files, which is ineffective since admins can always take ownership. you can try editing the registry offline: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-edit-windows-registry-key-values-without-booting-in-windows/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) - [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Run regedit at SYSTEM right:

```
psexec -i -d -s %windir%\regedit.exe
```

Run regedit at SYSTEM right Windows 2003/XP:

```
ntsd -c qd regedit
```

Comment: Or navigate to that key. Go to Permissions -> Advanced. Go to Change Owner ship. Take ownership. Then remove the deny permission

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your using Windows Explorer, which is closely linked to Internet Explorer, as shell to run regedit.exe. A workaround is to use the command prompt to run regedit.exe. Just follow these instructions:

1. Run the command prompt by pressing the Windows key and R simultaneously.
2. Type regedit.exe in the command prompt and execute it by pressing Enter.
3. The registry editor appears. Undo your change of the permission of the registry key using the registry editor.